# Get Week Start and End Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get all the week start and end dates from Current month, Suppose my week starts from **Saturday** and ends on **Friday**, I have tried following...

The following Query is part of a table-valued function in which I am passing the start date of current month and it returns a table runtime.

```
Declare @fromDate date
DECLARE @date date = GETUTCDATE()
DECLARE @tmpWeeks Table([WeekStart] date, [WeekEnd] date)
SET @fromDate = CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @date), 0) as date)
    ;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
   , dates as (
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @fromdate )+1, 0))) [DateValue]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
from n as deka cross join n as hecto
)
Insert into @tmpWeeks
select 
WeekStart   = min(DateValue), WeekEnd = max(DateValue)
from dates
group by datepart(week,DateValue)
select * from @tmpWeeks
```

It gives me following result.

```
WeekStart  WeekEnd
---------- ----------
2021-06-01 2021-06-04
2021-06-05 2021-06-11
2021-06-12 2021-06-18
2021-06-19 2021-06-25
2021-06-26 2021-06-30
```

> The above result is partially true but, if we see that here the First record's `WeekStart` date is `2021-06-01` but it should have `2021-05-29`
> (on Saturday)
>
> Likewise for the last record it is showing  `WeekEnd` as
> `2021-06-30` but it should have `2021-07-02`

so after considering above conditions the expected result would look like following..

```
WeekStart  WeekEnd
---------- ----------
2021-05-29 2021-06-04
2021-06-05 2021-06-11
2021-06-12 2021-06-18
2021-06-19 2021-06-25
2021-06-26 2021-07-02
```

Any help !?

Comment: The typical way of solving this is to create [a Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with precalculated dates for the next eg 10-20 years, with extra columns (possibly indexed) for year, month,quarter, semester, week number, week start and end, day name, etc. The size of the table is very small. Querying becomes a lot easier and performance improves by orders of magnitude. What used to require a full table scan and calculations becomes a simple grouping over an indexed column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaked OP version a bit

```
Declare @fromDate date;
DECLARE @date date = GETUTCDATE();
declare @m int = month(@date);
-- -2 to shift start of week to Saturday
-- -5 to shift start to a previous month
SET @fromDate = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, @date) - 5, 0) -2;
-- 11 weeks to cover month of interest fo sure
with t as (
    select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n) )
, dates as (
    select [DateS] = dateadd(week, n, @fromdate)
    from t 
)
-- take current month only
select [DateS], dateadd(dd, 6, [DateS]) [DateE]
from dates
where @m in (month([DateS]), month(dateadd(dd, 6, [DateS])));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a query like this:

```
declare @fromDate date = '06-02-2021'

set @fromDate = 
  case datepart(dw,@fromDate)
    when 7 then @fromDate
    else dateadd(day, - datepart(dw,@fromDate), @fromDate)
  end

;with weeks as (
  select datepart(week, @fromDate) w, @fromDate d, datepart(weekday, @fromDate) dd
  union all
  select datepart(week, dateadd(day, 1, d)), dateadd(day, 1, d), datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, 1, d)) from weeks where d <= '2022-01-01'
)
select dateadd(day, -1, min(d)) as weekstart, max(d) as weekend
from weeks
where dd in (1,6)
group by w
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec098e71d8c31d968492cf0c0c61ab5f)

Recursive cte's works pretty well auto generating dates, like your case.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried it, It is correct for last record, but for the first record it is showing the wrong ```WeekStart``` date, can you help ?

Comment: Just replace `'06-01-2021'` by your starting date `'2021-05-29'` in the upper select (the 3 times it appears)

Comment: That's the date I want as result, is there a way we can do this more automatically ?

Comment: It's not clear on your question. Do you want to build a table with start/end dates, or you want to build this at runtime? please be clear.

Comment: I have edited the question,  also I am passing the first day of month as a parameter and it returns me the table as a result.

Comment: Just initialize your `@fromDate` variable to your needs. I have added to the code.